# Login using API in Ionic 6

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native, capacitor

```js
## login.page.ts ##

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/services/auth/auth.service';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AlertService } from 'src/services/alert/alert.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss']
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private alertService: AlertService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onLogin(form: NgForm) {
    this.authService.login(form.value.username, form.value.password).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.alertService.presentToast("Logged In");
        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/welcome');
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        this.alertService.presentToast("Failed");
        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/login');
      }
    );
  }

}
```

```css
## login.page.scss ##

ion-content.background{
    --background: url(../../assets/img/staffandtruck.jpg) 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
## login.page.html ##

<ion-content padding class="background">

  <ion-card>
        <img src="assets/img/logo2.png"/>
    </ion-card>

    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-content>
        <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin(form)">

          <ion-item>
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="person-circle"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label position="floating">Staff ID</ion-label>
            <ion-input  type="email" name="username" ngModel required></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="key"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" name="password" ngModel required></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          
            <ion-card-content>
              <ion-button expand="block" color="primary" type="submit">Log in</ion-button>
            </ion-card-content>
          
        </form>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

i am new here and beginner in Ionic Framework. Is there anyone can help me and teach me on how to create a login using API that call username and password without create a **Model** for **User**? I don't know how to startup and implement this API. This is my environment setup for Ionic.
[My environment setup for Ionic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSoXe.png). This is for environment service that calling API for login [EnvService.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gFLA.png). This is for auth service [AuthService.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmYea.png). But, that all not functioning as I wish.

Comment: Check this https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-ui-forms-theming/

Comment: @AthifShaffy thanks for replied me. I have done with design the login form. Now, i need to proceed with environment setup for login function that using API. Can you helping me?

Comment: You can use firebase, check this out https://www.positronx.io/ionic-firebase-authentication-tutorial-with-examples/

Comment: @AthifShaffy thanks buddy. But I need to build an offline application. I heard that SQLite, PouchDB and CouchDB is the most suitable right? Or is there others way that I can use.

Comment: Yeah, you can use sqlite, check this out https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-sqlite-queries/